# Odoo: add custom menu item in Settings section

Tags: odoo

Odoo v10.0

Is it possible to add custom menu item on left sidebar in top-level "Settings" section?

[image]

For example here, in "Settings" section in navbar I have "Dashboard", "Users" and others. I have my custom module (addon) that's installed in system. I want to control some settings of my addon from UI as admin.

Ideally, such as UI should be in "Settings -> on left-side bar MyAddon -> and its sub-items". Otherwise, it should be in top-level navbar as the separate section.

Please advise where I can see (link to code) such as example.

Thanks

CC @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to put your menu under Settings -> Users

use **parent** id of any menu to put your menu under that menu.

```
<menuitem id="your_ui_menu_id" name="UI" parent="base.menu_administration" />
```

Comment: what is the file and where it's located for this?

Comment: this menuitem located at addons -> base -> base_menu.xml

Comment: hmm, found it in "/odoo/odoo/base/base_menu.xml"  but it's not updating. even after server restarting. Here how I start odoo

` ./odoo-bin --log-level=debug --addons-path=./addons,../myaddon`

Comment: try ./odoo-bin --addons-path=./addons,../myaddon --update=Your_module_name

Comment: still doesn't update. I even tried to edit other names to see if it affects UI -- no result

Comment: then i suggest menualy upgrade your module after restarting service

Comment: or you can try upgrading the base module:

 ./odoo-bin --addons-path=./addons,../myaddon --update=Your_module_name,base

Comment: make sure your module is depends  on "base" check your __manifest__.py

Comment: @ADVALAKI, thanks for `--update` option, it worked, but only after I added <record> tag.

Comment: no need to add record tag write it in <odoo><data><menuitem/></data></odoo>